# How to Update Data in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

First, sorry for my bad english, if you don't understand what I'm saying, you can ask for it and I will search for another suitable and precise words.

Now, I've been working with codeigniter in this last 2 weeks, so I got so many question for it, but I found 1 which is hanging on my mind.

I started with simple CRUD, then make it advanced, it's good so far, until I got stuck while updating data. When I click the "submit" button, I get only 404 page. And when I see the database, nothing change.

Here's the controller's code:

```
<?php if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
Class Master_user extends CI_Controller {   
function __construct(){  
    parent::__construct();  
    $this->load->model('mod_master_user');
    $this->load->library('datatables');
}
public function index(){
    if ($this->session->userdata('type') == 'admin') {
        $data['hasil'] = $this->mod_master_user->getall();
        $datum['content'] = $this->load>view('master_user/view',$data,true);
        $this->load->view('main',$datum);
    } else if ($this->session->userdata('type') == 'user'){
        $a= $this->load->model('m_absensi');
        $aa["content"] = $this->load->view('absensi/form',$a,true);
        $this->load->view("absensi/mainUser",$aa);
    }
}

public function tambah_data(){
    if($this->input->post('nama')){
        $this->mod_master_user->tambah();
        redirect('master_user');
    }else{
    $this->load->view('master_user/add'); 
    }
}

public function update_data($id_user)**//i use this method for updating data**{
    if($this->input->post('submit')){
        $this->mod_master_user->update($id_user);
        redirect('master_user/index');
    }
    $data['hasil']=$this->mod_master_user->getById($id_user);
    $this->load->view('master_user/edit',$data);
}

public function delete_data($id_user){
    $this->mod_master_user->delete($id_user);
    redirect('master_user');
}

public function error() 
{ 
    $this->output->set_status_header('404'); 
    $data['content'] = '404';  
    $this->load->view('master_user/404',$data); 
}

public function print_report()
{
    $this->load->view('master_user/print');
}

public function jam_masuk()
{
    $this->load->view('master_user/jam_masuk');
}
```

}

Here comes the model's code:

```
<?php if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
Class Mod_master_user extends CI_Model{ 

var $tabel_name = 'master_user';

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function getall(){
    $ambil_data = $this->db->get('master_user');//mengambil tabel master_user

    if ($ambil_data->num_rows() > 0 ){ //jika data lebih dari 0
        foreach ($ambil_data->result() as $data){
            $hasil[] = $data;
        }
        return $hasil;
    }
}

public function tambah(){
    $id_user = $this->input->post('id_user');       
    $nama  = $this->input->post('nama');    
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $tanggal_lahir = $this->input->post('tanggal_lahir');
    $tempat_lahir = $this->input->post('tempat_lahir');
    $role = $this->input->post('role');
    $data = array (
        'id_user'=> $id_user,       
        'nama'=>$nama,  
        'password'=>md5($password),
        'tanggal_lahir'=>date('Y-m-d',strtotime($tanggal_lahir)),
        'tempat_lahir'=>$tempat_lahir,
        'role'=>$role   
    );  
    $this->db->where('id_user',$id_user);
    $this->db->insert('master_user', $data);
}

public function update($id_user)**//i use this method to updating data**{   
    $id_user=$this->input->post('id_user');      
    $nama=$this->input->post('nama');    
    $password=$this->input->post('password');
    $tanggal_lahir=$this->input->post('tanggal_lahir');
    $tempat_lahir=$this->input->post('tempat_lahir');
    $role=$this->input->post('role');
      $data = array (
        'id_user' => $id_user,      
        'nama'  => $nama,   
        'password'=> $password,
        'tanggal_lahir'=> $tanggal_lahir,
        'tempat_lahir'=> $tempat_lahir,
        'role'=>$role
    );
    $this->db->where('id_user',$id_user);
    $this->db->update('master_user',$data); //update data 
}

public function getById($id_user){  //mengambil data dari db berdasarkan   id (primary key)
    return $this->db->get_where('master_user',array('id_user'=>$id_user))->row();
}

public function delete($id_user){   
    $this->db->where('id_user',$id_user);
    $this->db->delete('master_user'); //query delete data 
}

public function cek_user_login($username, $password) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('NAMA', $username);
    $this->db->where('PASSWORD', md5($password));

    $query = $this->db->get($this->tabel_name, 1);



    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        $this->db->limit(1);
        return $query->row_array();
    }
}

public function validasi()
{
    $nama = $this->input->post('nama');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $check = $this->mod_master_user->check($nama, md5($password));
    if($check->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        //login berhasil, buat session
        //$this->session->set_userdata('username',$username);
        redirect('master_user');
    }
    else
    {
        //login gagal
        //$this->session->set_flashdata('message','Username atau password salah');
        redirect('users');
    }
}
```

}

So far, I get no answer on other forums, so I asked for the answer here :)
Any answer/help will be appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: Where is your view code.?

Answer (score 0):

It's been some time since I used CodeIgniter.

Are you loading the input class? so you can actually receive $_GET and $_POST data? I think it does this by default actually.

This might be a bit too simple, but are you calling the right URI and are you sure its reaching your view??

Might help to see your view, are you using the form helper for this? https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

If you get 404, then the problem is in your form **action** tag. It means it doesn't post to the right url.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely (if not surely) due to a bad route.

In config/routes.php, you need a route like: `$route['master_user/update/(:any)'] = 'master_user/update_data/$1;`

And in your view you would need a form with the action pointing to that route, such as:

`<form action="master_user/update_data/1">
   <!-- your fields and submit button -->
 </form>`

Where the number 1 (in the action url) is the id of the register being updated.